# ssl security information on internet explorer 6

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, mootools

I dont want that my webpage show security information about this page contains both secure and nonsecure... this only happen in ie6, i am testing with the program ietester. I know that the problem is in file mootools-1.11-uncompressed.js in this line

```
if(!$("ie_ready")){var C=(window.location.protocol=="https:")?"://0":"javascript:void(0);";document.write('<script id="ie_ready" defer src="'+C+'"><\/script>');$("ie_ready").onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState=="complete"){A();}};}}else{window.addListener("load",A);document.addListener("DOMContentLoaded",A);
```

i already try change the `://0` by `https://0` and `javascript` and `javascript:false` and `#` but the problem continues, when i remove this line from the mootools file the warning doesnt show but the code that i have to show some calendar doesnt work also, because i have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  window.addEvent('domready', function() {
```

and this doesnt work if i remove that line, can anyone help me??

Comment: You should edit your post and wrap all your code in `<code>` and `</code>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

i have had similar issues with mootools 1.11 and SSL, try using this version (includes 2 fixes):

http://www.webtogs.co.uk/js/mtu.js

in the code you pasted, remove the defer and try that.